# Implementing a rule engine in laravel

Tags: laravel, rules

I am trying to build a rule engine for a medical app, this is the user interface i build

[image]

[image]

where on satisfying the conditions, it will send the action to the account specified like an alert or email.

Given below is my db structure

```
Schema::create('rules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('rule_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('notification_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('account')->nullable();
            $table->string('measurement')->nullable();
            $table->string('rule')->nullable();
            $table->string('value')->nullable();
            $table->string('condition')->nullable();
            $table->string('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('changed_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I was thinking of saving the rules in the rule field as an array and loop through the array to check if condition is met. Is there is a better or more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Rename the table you currently have to `criterias` and create another table called `rules` (keeping things consistent with your UI) then store your rules in the `rules` table with a `fk` to the `criterias` table.

Comment: Were you able to complete the project? is it on Github? I have similar reqt and would like to see an example if you don't mind